# Top N records based and group by other column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have table in SQL SERVER with 3 columns
`Team (VARCHAR)`, `Player (VARCHAR)` and `Point (int)`
There are 15 unique teams, each team has 20+ players and each player has a point.

I would like to get TOP 10 player from each team based on sum of all his point (Because, each player may has multiple rows with different point he scored).

I Tried,

```
SELECT TOP 10 Team,Player, 
   ISNULL(SUM([Point]), 0) 
   FROM [SportsTable] 
GROUP BY Teams, Player 
ORDER BY 3 DESC
```

But got only TOP 10 players (only 10 rows) globally. I need `15 * 10 = 150` rows for each team.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Team ORDER BY SUM(Point) DESC)`

```
SELECT
    Team,
    Player,
    Point
FROM(
    SELECT
        Team,
        Player,
        Point = ISNULL(SUM(Point), 0),
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Team ORDER BY ISNULL(SUM(Point), 0) DESC)
    FROM SportsTable
    GROUP BY Team, Player
)t
WHERE RN <= 10
```